# manage duplicates when inserting into a linked list

Tags: python, recursion, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I wrote an algorithm for inserting into a linked list of Course objects sorted by their `number` member variable. It works well, except when I try to insert duplicates, like two instances of 2420 for example. The list `__str__` output currently looks like this:

```
cs1400 Introduction to Programming Grade:3.6 Credit Hours: 4 
cs1410 C++ Programming Grade:2.6 Credit Hours: 4 
cs2420 Introduction to Data Structures Grade:3.2 Credit Hours: 4 
cs2810 Computer Architecture Grade:3.8 Credit Hours: 3
```

and here is my code for the insert method

```
def insert(self, course=None):
        """Insert the specified Course in Course Number ascending order.""" 
        def insert_helper(cursor, course):

            if course is None:
                return

            if course.number <= self.head.number: # start of the list
                self.head = course
                return

            if cursor.next is None or course.number <= cursor.next.number: # 
                course.next = cursor.next
                cursor.next = course
                return

            insert_helper(cursor.next, course)


        if self.head is None:
            self.head = course
            return
        cursor = self.head
        insert_helper(cursor, course)
```

The trick is wrapping my mind around the recursion frames. I hope to get a better hang of this soon.

Comment: What does it do wrong when you try to insert a duplicate, and what do you **want** it to do?

Comment: so you need to add a case for when the course.number == course.next that way you can account for duplicate course numbers, obviously you will have to know **how** to handle the **duplicate** course numbers...

Comment: @DavidK I would like it to insert as another entry in the list.

Comment: For a question like this, it would help to post the examples of the input and output in each case where the program worked an in the case where it didn't work. I suspect you just didn't try enough different test data to diagnose the error correctly.

Comment: Please describe the current input/output and the desired output, and share a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe duplicated course numbers are the problem, per se.

There is an error in your program here:

```
            if course.number <= self.head.number: # start of the list
                self.head = course
                return
```

If you ever execute the last two lines in this code snippet, your list becomes a singleton list containing `course` and nothing else.

Compare this to the next `if` statement, where if the condition is true then you execute

```
                course.next = cursor.next
```

You need to set `course.next` to something in both places.

Also notice that if `course.number <= self.head.number` is not true during the first call to `insert_helper`, it won't be true on any of the recursive calls either. It might have been better to handle this case before the first call to that function.